# No suitable propagation model available

Tags: python

I try to use Bellhop Acoustic Toolbox and run code from there https://patel999jay.github.io/post/bellhop-acoustic-toolbox/

But each time when I launch cell with codes I get an error
ValueError: No suitable propagation model available

And I have no idea what should I do to fix it.

can you please help me?

Comment: Please [do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://github.com/org-arl/arlpy/issues/58

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem you have to do the next actions:

1. pip install arlpy
2. Download atWin10_2020_11_4.zip Binaries (zip file) for Windows 10 from http://oalib.hlsresearch.com/AcousticsToolbox/
3. Found bellhop.exe (my folder \acoustic toolbox\atWin10_2020_11_4\atWin10_2020_11_4\windows-bin-20201102)
4. create PATH variable with mentioned above path (only folder, do not include file!!)

enjoy))